# enable ethernet on ubee router

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I am trying to enable ethernet on my ubee Time Warner router.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rsjG.png)

I can connect via wireless and everything works fine, when I use wired I get not DHCP address and the lights on the back don't light up when connected.

If I reset the router, the ethernet lights on the back (and the connected devices) light up briefly.

Tried two devices and two cables.

Comment: Have you called Time Warner support? These things are usually locked down by the vendor, there is rarely much you can do... I assume you have tried logging in to the router as per these steps: http://www.timewarnercable.com/en/support/faqs/faqs-internet/homewifi/how-do-i-change-my-wifi-settings1.html, if you can't change the settings for ethernet, you need to call TW support

Comment: I agree; You should contact Time Warner.